# Auto filter by todays date

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to sort by two columns. Current State and Approved Date. The approved date needs to be the current date.

When i tried debugging the code, when i add the watch in to see what is the date being assigned, it shows for example 11/August/2013 which is the same as what i have in the spreadsheet for some cells that also meet the current state condition, yet it still filters them out when its meant to keep them in there. Is there a reason why this is not working?

```
Dim w As Integer, b As Integer, rngData2 As Range
Set rngData2 = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
w = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Current State", Range("A1:AZ1"), 0)
b = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Approved Date", Range("A1:AZ1"), 0)

rngData2.AutoFilter Field:=w, Criteria1:=Array( _
"Approved", "Detailed Impact Assessment", "Draft – Yet to be Tabled at CCCM", _
"Initial Impact Assessment", "New", "On Hold", "Pending Approval - Execution", _
"Pending Approval - IIA"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

rngData2.AutoFilter Field:=b, Criteria1:=Array( _
Date, "TBC"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: This looks like visual basic, so I added the `vb.net` tag. In case I was wrong please correct it...

Comment: @home Actually, it is VBA. I have already corrected it.

Comment: You have been asking this same question (or versions of it) quite a few times. Actually you have been referring different problems which, apparently you/others have solved (although you haven't ever awarded any answer), now I see various problems additionally to the one you are referring. For example: w = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match can crash in case of not finding a match. Do you understand that the goal here is helping programmers with specific problems, not doing their work, don't you?

Comment: I've modified the title from 'sort' to 'filter'. There is nothing to do with sorting in the code. Sorting is mentioned again in the question but, again, it is about filtering.

Comment: Yes it is another date format issue which is still not resolved :(